# Last line of Stack Overflow profile description is half hidden on mobile device

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, mobile-web

When I open my Stack Overflow profile on mobile device (I am using Android Ice Cream Sandwich on Google Nexus S). The last line of of my "about me" (text in the grey box) appears cut at half vertically.

I do not have a screenshot, because this happens only on device, not on browser. I hope this is very minor issue. Could anyone else please confirm. I will try to edit this post with a screenshot soon.

Comment: I'm sure they figured out a way to take screenshots on Android...

Comment: Also, try clicking "show more". I bet it's by design to get people to click that link.

Comment: It is not just the last line. The mobile version shows the first X lines until you click "show more".

Answer (score 1):

It's actually by design. Clicking read more will show the rest of the "about me" box.